# Parsing variable from script to html function

Tags: html

I'm trying to pass a variable `weekendingdate` to an HTML function to create a popup but somehow it doesn't work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <h2>Select Week Ending date  </h2>  
  <br /> 
  <input type="date" name="Weekendingdate">
  <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
  <br />  
  <script>
    function myFunction() {
      alert(Weekendingdate);
    }
   </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to either pass the value of the input as an argument to the function - or get the value within the function. Note that since you have the input type="date" - you can set the values of the date portions individually - or use the built in date picker. Its also worth noting that all the browsers treat inputs with type="date" differently - so you may want to alter that approach.

Anyway - the flow is - change set the date in the date field - then click the button and you will get your alert giving the date (value of the input) that you entered.

Also - one other thing - in dev, its better to console.log() your results for testing / debugging. I left it as the alert you had, but wanted to change it :)

```js
function myFunction() {
  let Weekendingdate = document.getElementsByName('Weekendingdate')[0].value;
  alert(Weekendingdate);
}
```

```html
<h2>Select Week Ending date  </h2>  
<input type="date" name="Weekendingdate">
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```